# clean a folder contents during pre-integration-test phase

Tags: maven

I have parent pom where I'm trying to unpack some scripts, execute them inside  and in "pre-integration-test" phase, so it runs by default for all child modules.

My problem here is I need to delete the contents of certain directory each time it runs. I tried using ant-plugin which never runs in the pre-integration-phase. Also to note I'm calling several profiles while building the project.

```
mvn clean install -Pprofile1,profile2,integration
```

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
   <execution>
      <id>compile</id>
      <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
      <configuration>
      <tasks>
        <delete>
          <fileset dir="checkout\myproject\specific_directory\**.*"/>
        <delete/>
      </tasks>
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
   </execution>
 </executions>
```

Overall I have four plugins including ant clean all running in pre-integration-phase. Except ant clean up task all others run correctly.

Comment: Why not using the maven-clean-plugin ?

Comment: Tried it but same issue, Not running in pre-integration-test phase.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the documentation and on my personal experience i assume you configured the plugin in the wrong area. Furthermore have you called mvn via:

```
mvn verify
```

to execute integration-test phase.

```xml
<build>
  [...]
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
   <executions>
     <execution>
      <id>cleanup</id>
      <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>clean</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <filesets>
          <fileset>
            <directory>some/relative/path</directory>
            <includes>
              <include>**/*.tmp</include>
              <include>**/*.log</include>
            </includes>
         </fileset>
        </filesets>
     </configuration>
    </execution>
    <executions>
  </plugin>
  [...]
</build>
```